# Understand quadratic divergence in first-order correction to 2-point green's function in $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions, correlation-functions

Concerning only scalar QED here and momentum configuration for Feynman's diagrams. For 2-point green's function of $\phi^4$ theory$$G(x_1,x_2)=\langle\Omega|T(\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\exp\left(\frac{-i\lambda}{4!}\int d^4y~\phi^4(y)\right)|\Omega\rangle.$$

As with perturbation theory, we have $$G(x_1,x_2)=\langle\Omega|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|\Omega\rangle+\langle\Omega|T\left\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\int~d^4y~\frac{-i\lambda}{4!}\phi^4(y)\right\}|\Omega\rangle+o(\lambda^2)$$ which we evaluate order by order using Wick's theorem. In particular, for the order $\lambda$ term, we have
$$\langle\Omega|T\left\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\int~d^4y~\frac{-i\lambda}{4!}\phi^4(y)\right\}|\Omega\rangle=\int d^4y(-i\lambda)\frac{1}{4!}\langle\Omega|4\cdot 3\cdot\mathcal{C}(\phi(x_1)\phi(y))\mathcal{C}(\phi(x_2)\phi(y))\mathcal{C}(\phi(y)\phi(y))|\Omega\rangle$$
having excluded disconnected graphs, where I hope you will excuse me for using $\mathcal{C}(\phi(x_1)\phi(y))$ to denote the contraction between $\phi(x_1)\phi(y)$ as I have no idea how to LaTeX wick contraction without simplerwick package, i.e. $$\mathcal{C}(\phi(x_1)\phi(y)):=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\frac{d^4k_1}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i}{k^2_1-m^2+i\epsilon}e^{-ik_1\cdot(x_1-y)}.$$
Consider the Fourier Transform of the $\lambda$ order term (denoted $G_\lambda$) I wrote above\begin{align}\mathcal{F}(G_\lambda)(p_1,p_2)&=\int~d^4 x_1d^4 x_2 G_\lambda(x_1,x_2)e^{-ip_1x_1-ip_2x_2}\\&=\frac{1}{2}(2\pi)^4\delta^4(p_1+p_2)\frac{i}{p_1^2-m^2}\frac{i}{p_2^2-m^2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int~\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}.\end{align}
I am trying to understand the divergence of the integral
$$\int d^4k\frac{i}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}.$$
The technique given to me was that (btw we are in flat spacetime with mostly minus metric) we should do a substitution with $ik_E^0=k^0$, $\vec{k}_E=\vec{k}$ so the integral becomes$$I=\int^{iT_f}_{iT_i}dk^0_E\int^\infty_{-\infty}d^3\vec{k}_E\frac{1}{k_E^2+m^2}$$ where $k^2_E:=(k^0_E)^2+(\vec{k}_E)^2$.

**Question 1**
In calculating $S$-matrix elements, we have $T_f\to\infty$ and $T_i\to-\infty$. In this case should not the integration range go from $i\infty$ to $-i\infty$ or is there no difference to just write $\int^\infty_\infty~dk^0_E$?

**Question 2**
When estimating the value of the above integral, why is it the case that when $|k_E|\to \alpha$ for large real positive valued $\alpha$, the integral goes to $$I\sim\int^\alpha\frac{|k_E|^3}{|k_E|^2}d|k_E|$$ I certainly understand that $m$ contribution can be neglected, but I fail to make much sense on how we go from $d^4k_E$ to $d|k_E|$